# T-SQL Aggregation of Overlapping Date Times From Large View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

The task is: I have an application that is similar to a time card if you will. However, any employee may have 1 or more claim entries that overlap with another. The aggregation is currently being done in VB.NET, however there are huge performance issues this way. So, my object here is to use T-SQL if possible to do this for me. Hopefully this makes sense. Each claim entry will have a notes field that should be combined if the entries overlap. So, it works something like this:
*Claim-1: ClaimID-123 Start-"9:00" End-"10:00" Notes-"Testing 1"
Claim-2: ClaimID-456 Start-"9:30" End-"10:30" Notes-"Testing 2"
**Desired Result:** Start-"9:00", End-"10:30", concatenating the notes column to include notes from both claim entries.*

SQL Code Start

```
   SELECT s1.StartTime,
   MIN(t1.EndTime) As EndTime
   FROM vw_ClaimLine s1
   INNER JOIN vw_ClaimLine t1 ON s1.StartTime <= t1.EndTime
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM vw_ClaimLine t2
   WHERE t1.EndTime >= t2.StartTime AND t1.EndTime < t2.EndTime)
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM vw_ClaimLine s2
   WHERE s1.StartTime > s2.StartTime AND s1.StartTime <= s2.EndTime)
   AND
   s1.RecDate BETWEEN '4-01-2018' AND '4-1-2018' AND s1.ProvidedBy = 233
   GROUP BY s1.StartTime
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be more helpful that your bio.

Comment: I outlined my desired result. I figured a little background on what the application is used for might be important as well. The result should yield a start time from 9:00 and an end time of 10:30 as well as concatenating the notes column(s).
Combined Claim:
Start-"9:00"
End-"10:30"
Notes-"Testing 1 Testing 2"

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: the only thing we need to solve this is the table definition of vw_ClaimLine